# IdentityServer4 OIDC-Client authorize redirect loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net, azure, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I've built an implementation of **IdentityServer4**, integrating **ASP Identity** running **ASP.NET Core** utilizing the **Implicit Flow**. *(We're changing to an PKCE configuration later on, but whatever.)* The application manages user signins across multiple web applications running **ASP.NET/AngularJS/OIDC-Client**. When running everything locally on **IIS Express**, everything works as intended. I can login, logout, silently refresh, life is good. However, after deploying to **Azure** - I get stuck in an infinite redirect loop attempting to log in and I'm at my wits' end.

The first call to a protected web resource redirects me back to the login service. That's fine. After logging in, I'm sent to the web resource as expected - but, here is where the redirect loop begins.

From the **IdentityServer** logs on **Application Insights** I read messages like;

- `Client list checked and origin: "https://webapp.net" is allowed.`
- `CorsPolicyService allowed origin: "https://webapp.net"`
- `Client configuration validation for client "webclient" succeeded.`
- `Token validation success`

I can see that the claim types and user info contains espected values, and the `GET request` to `"https://loginservice.net/-well-known/openid-configuration"` returns OK (with the expected configurations). I've also verified that the **access** and **id tokens** are valid, again containing the expected data.

But, the `POST request` to `"https://loginservice.net/connect/accesstokenvalidation"` still fails with a 404.

The **OIDC-Client** on my web app is configured like this:

```
vm.userManager = new Oidc.UserManager({
    authority: authorityUrl,
    redirect_uri: windowLocation + '/callback.html',
    silent_redirect_uri: windowLocation + '/silent.html',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: windowLocation + '/index.html',
    client_id: 'appsimplicit',
    scope: 'openid profile role appsmanagement',
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    checkSessionInterval: 2000
});
```

My **callback.html** looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/js/oidc-client.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Oidc.UserManager().signinRedirectCallback().then(function(user) {
            window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to fix this? The same behaviour persists across different browsers; Firefox, Chrome, Edge.. I have no idea why it works locally but not deployed to Azure.